# Grails links only work if logged in

Tags: grails, spring-security

Building a grails (2.2.0) site and having strange issue where the links (in header) only work when user is logged in. These particular links are general links that should be for everyone.

When I click the link(s) it takes me to a blank white page that says "notvalid"

I'm guessing there must be a way to enable these links or make them public so not to require login....

Any help would be appreciated.

**Snippet from main.gsp**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-main">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-center">
            <li><a href="${createLink(controller: 'main', action: 'contact')}">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="${createLink(controller: 'main', action: 'calendar')}">Calendar</a></li>
```

**Snippet from MainController**

```
class MainController {

// show events up to a two weeks after they closed
def Calendar() {
    // TODO: this action is not working without authorization
    def events = Event.findAllByBidEndDateTimeGreaterThan(new Date() - 14);
    render(view: 'calendar', model: [events: events])
}

def contact() {
    render(view: 'contact')
}
```

}

**interceptUrlMap below:**

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/dashboard/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
    '/home/**'     : ['permitAll'],
    '/**'          : ["permitAll"],
    '/'                    : ['permitAll'],
    '/index'               : ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp'           : ['permitAll'],
    '/main.gsp'           : ['permitAll'],
    '/auth.gsp'           : ['permitAll'],
    '/contact'              : ['permitAll'],
    '/calendar'             : ['permitAll'],
    '/assets/**'           : ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**'            : ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**'           : ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**'        : ['permitAll'],
    '/**/fonts/**'         : ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico'      : ['permitAll']
```

]

Comment: You are going to need to provide a lot more information for this question to be answerable. How about an example of one of these links? How about including your URL mappings when it comes to security?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore - thank you for the advice, I just added edit above which should hopefully give a little better idea what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

need to add something like this to Config.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
        '/'                    : ['permitAll'],
        '/index'               : ['permitAll'],
        '/index.gsp'           : ['permitAll'],
        '/about.gsp'           : ['permitAll'],
        '/about'               : ['permitAll'],
        '/assets/**'           : ['permitAll'],
        '/**/js/**'            : ['permitAll'],
        '/**/css/**'           : ['permitAll'],
        '/**/images/**'        : ['permitAll'],
        '/**/fonts/**'         : ['permitAll'],
        '/**/favicon.ico'      : ['permitAll']
]



package com.grails

import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured

@Secured(['permitAll'])
class PersonController {

}
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking too but still shows notvalid for those links. 
Maybe I'm missing something in that list? 
I've included it above so you can see what I have listed so far.

Comment: can you try adding @Secured(['permitAll']) annotation to the links?

Comment: Hm, added as you said but it gives "Config.groovy: 136: unable to resolve class Secured , unable to find class for annotation"

Comment: you should have an import to import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured

Comment: This should be added to the controller

Comment: Ok, i've added the import to MainController.groovy but does not seem to make a difference. Still gives "unable to resolve class Secured , unable to find class for annotation". Do I need to add on the main.gsp file?

Comment: what version of spring security are you using. I'll try to recreate it

Comment: It's Version 1.2.7.3, for some reason can't get anything to stop from displaying notvalid page

Comment: I'd be glad to show you as well...something definitely does not make sense here